# Typescript TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting an error of 'collection' undefined when trying to push object.

```
groupShortlists(lists: ProductShortlist[]) {
    const grouped = lists.reduce((groupedList, list) => {
        groupedList[list.collection] = [...groupedList[list.collection] || [], list];
        return groupedList;
      }, {});

    return Object.keys(grouped).map(key => grouped[key]);
  }


this.shortlistsCategory = [];
this.groupShortlists(this.shortLists).map((item, key) => {
      this.shortlistsCategory.push({
        collection: item[key].collection,
        list: [],
      });
    });
```

The exact error says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Is this the proper way of using push. Any help would be appreciated. :D

Comment: In map function, the first arg will be a single obj/item of that array and the second will be `index`. So make sure item[0] exists.

Comment: What does `groupShortlists` do? Can you include a code snippet please

Comment: Updated. I include what does groupShortlists do.

Comment: After seeing your snippet for the groupShortlist method, it looks like the returned array may have nested arrays (which could be an issue). Can you post an example of `ProductShortlist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the `item` is already the value at the index `key` of `shortLists`. You can do either `item.collection` or `shortLists[key].collection`, but not both.

Also, using `.map` already returns the specified object, so there's no need to use `.map` and a `.push` (it's not as semantic).

Below is an example setting shortlists category to the `.map` return value.

```js
this.shortlistsCategory = this.groupShortlists(this.shortLists)
  .map(item => {
    return {
      collection: item.collection,
      list: []
    };
  });
```

Link to `.map` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map